# Not working on azure server but works fine in local environment?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, azure-web-app-service

I have jQuery Ajax method to call a web method in C# code. The code works fine in local environment but it does not work in server. But some web method and jQuery Ajax calls work fine with normal SQL statement, but with a stored procedure in web method which returns some data it does not work. It shows an error message as

> {Message: "There was an error processing the request.",StackTrace:"", ExceptionType: ""}
>   ExceptionType:""
>   Message:"There was an error processing the request."
>   StackTrace:""

Here's my Ajax call...

```
$.ajax({
            url: "AutoRFQ_Vendors_SP.aspx/BindGrid"
            , type: "POST"
            , data: JSON.stringify(objdrpdata)
            , contentType: "application/json;"
            , success: function (data) {
                $body.removeClass("loading");
                var vendorsource = {
                    datatype: "json"
                    , localdata: data.d
                    , datafields: [
                        {
                            name: 'CommonMakerNameDisplay'
                        }
                        , {
                            name: 'EqpExtendType'
                        }
                        , {
                            name: 'CommonMakerName'
                        }
                        , {
                            name: 'IsForAutoRFQ'
                        }
                        , {
                            name: 'VendorName'
                        }
                        , {
                            name: 'CurrencyCode'
                        }
                        , {
                            name: 'Proc_Vendors_AllowedCurrencyID'
                        }
                        , {
                            name: 'SortCode'
                        }
                        , {
                            name: 'xSortCode'
                        }
                        , {
                            name: 'IsTitle'
                        }
                        , {
                            name: 'NoOfRFQs'
                        }
                        , {
                            name: 'NoOfOrders'
                        }
                        , {
                            name: 'TotalPOAmtInUSD'
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Here's my web method:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string BindGrid(string vslFilter, string yearFilter, string eqpmtFilter) 
{
      DataTable dt = null;

      string gridvendorlist = "";

      try 
      {
           if (HttpContext.Current.Session["P_Hub_AutoRFQVendorDataTable"] == null || (string) HttpContext.Current.Session["P_Hub_AutoRFQVslFilter"] != vslFilter || (string) HttpContext.Current.Session["P_Hub_AutoRFQYearFilter"] != yearFilter || (string) HttpContext.Current.Session["P_Hub_AutoRFQEqpmtFilter"] != eqpmtFilter) 
           {
               string vslFilterType = "", vslFilterValue = "";

               if (vslFilter.Length == 3) 
                   vslFilter = "VSL-" + vslFilter;

               string[] vslType = vslFilter.Trim().Split('-');

               if (vslType[0].ToString().Trim().ToUpper() == "VSL") 
               {
                   vslFilterType = "VSL";
                   vslFilterValue = vslType[1].ToString();
               } 
               else if (vslFilter != "-1") 
               {
                   vslFilterType = "Group";
                   vslFilterValue = vslFilter.ToString();
               }

               string spName = "W_Enh_CommonMakers_RFQVendors";

               string[] paramField = { "@CompanyCode", "@VslFilterType",
                                       "@VslFilterValue", "@NoOfYrToShow",
                                       "@EQ_EquipmentID" };
               object[] paramValue = { GenFuncs.COMPANYCODE,
                                       vslFilterType,
                                       vslFilterValue,
                                       yearFilter,
                                       eqpmtFilter };
               dt = DBFuncs.dbExecuteSP(spName, paramField, paramValue);

               HttpContext.Current.Session["P_Hub_AutoRFQVendorDataTable"] = dt;
               HttpContext.Current.Session["P_Hub_AutoRFQVendorSelectedRowIndex"] = null;
               HttpContext.Current.Session["P_Hub_AutoRFQ_ScrollIndex"] = null;
               HttpContext.Current.Session["P_Hub_AutoRFQVslFilter"] = vslFilter;
               HttpContext.Current.Session["P_Hub_AutoRFQYearFilter"] = yearFilter;
               HttpContext.Current.Session["P_Hub_AutoRFQEqpmtFilter"] = eqpmtFilter;

               gridvendorlist = Func_Ajax.GetJson(dt);
           } 
           else 
           {
               dt = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["P_Hub_AutoRFQVendorDataTable"];
               gridvendorlist = Func_Ajax.GetJson(dt);
           }
      } 
      catch (Exception err) 
      {
           GenFuncs.AddToErrLog("-1", "xxx", "Error", err.Message, Path.GetFileName(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath), "BindGrid");
      } 
      finally 
      {
           dt = null;
      }

      return gridvendorlist;
 }
```

Is there any extra thing I need to do in server?

Comment: Hi ..sorry ... is a Azure webApp .. or a Azure VM ? ..have you open the http port?

Comment: yse it is a Azure webApp ...yes i can open http port..

Comment: have you open it? ..and have you check in google chrome console the xhr request of your front end? (if is pointing the right server etc)

Comment: yes it pointing to my correct server only

Comment: try to activate error .with customError=off in web config

Comment: yes i activated but still won't work it shows {Message: "There was an error processing the request.", StackTrace: "", ExceptionType: ""}
ExceptionType
:
""
Message
:
"There was an error processing the request."
StackTrace
:
""

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After 5 hrs of explore i finally found some silly mistake which was in my web.config file

```
  <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
          <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
          </webServices>
        </scripting>
      </system.web.extensions>
```

works fine....Thank you